# ng-show doesn't work in form

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I create form and use AngularJs. I need display errors and I have a problem.
My expression for ng-show doesn't work.

My code:

```
<form name="createProductForm" ng-submit="createProduct(product)" novalidate>

    <input type="text" ng-model="product.name" ng-minlength="3" required> <br>
    <p ng-show="createProductForm.product.name.$error.required && createProductForm.product.name.$dirty">Nazwa produktu jest wymagana.</p>
    <p ng-show="createProductForm.product.name.$error.minlength && createProductForm.product.name.$dirty">Nazwa produktu jest zbyt krótka.</p>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="createProductForm.$invalid">Dodaj produkt</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Your input MUST have a name attribute

Comment: What do these two properties look like? `createProductForm.product.name.$error.required` and `createProductForm.product.name.$dirty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input tag **MUST** have a name attribute. `ngModel` does not provide validation states.

```
<input name="nameAttributeHere"/>

<p ng-show="createProductForm.nameAttributeHere.$error.required && createProductForm.nameAttributeHere.$dirty">...</p>
```

`ngModel` and form validation states are completely separate directives.

Comment: 'input' does not need a name attribute with ng-submit

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with `ngSubmit`. This is about form validation states

Comment: Yeah did a little digging and I believe you're correct.